# Why does the validation for lowercase letters always fail?

Tags: c++, char, lowercase

I am writing a program that takes a password as input and validates based on the following criteria:

- 8 characters or more
- at least one uppercase letter
- at least one lowercase letter
- at least one digit

The validation function successfully checks for all of the criteria except for lowercase letters even though the method is the same.

P.S. I am aware that using namespace standard is considered bad practice but for the sake of this program, it shouldn't cause any issues to my knowledge.

Main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Passwords.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string password;    //string for user input
    bool longEnough, foundUpper, foundLower, foundDigit;    //booleans to validate password

    for(int i = 3; i > 0; i--)  //loop 3 times or until valid password is entered
    {
        longEnough = false; //reset bools to false
        foundUpper = false;
        foundLower = false;
        foundDigit = false;
        getInput(password); //calling getInput function
        if(validatePass(password, longEnough, foundUpper, foundLower, foundDigit) == true)  //check if the password is valid
        {
            getValidOutput(password); //calls function to display output for valid password
            exit(0);    //end program
        }
        else
        {
            getInvalidOutput(password, longEnough, foundUpper, foundLower, foundDigit);   //calls function to display output for invalid password
            cout << "You have " << i-1 << " more attempts.\n";
        }
    }
    cout << "You have run out of attempts, the session has been locked.";
    exit(0);    //end program
}
```

Header file:

```
#ifndef PASSWORDS_H_INCLUDED
#define PASSWORDS_H_INCLUDED

using namespace std;

void getInput(string& password) //prompts and receives user input for password
{
    cout << "Please enter a password with at least 8 characters, one uppercase, one lowercase, and one digit: ";
    cin >> password;
}

bool validatePass(string password, bool& longEnough, bool& foundUpper, bool& foundLower, bool& foundDigit)  //checks if password is valid
{
    if(password.length() >= 8)  //check for length
    {
        longEnough = true;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++)  //check each character
    {
        char position = password.at(i); //set current character
        if(isupper(position) == true)   //check for uppercase letters
        {
            foundUpper = true;
        }
        if(islower(position) == true)   //check for lowercase letters
        {
            foundLower = true;
        }
        if(isdigit(position) == true)   //check for digits
        {
            foundDigit = true;
        }
    }
    if(longEnough == true && foundUpper == true && foundLower == true && foundDigit == true)    //return true if valid, return false otherwise
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

void getValidOutput(string password)    //output if the password is valid
{
    cout << "The password \"" << password << "\" is valid.";
}

void getInvalidOutput(string password, bool longEnough, bool foundUpper, bool foundLower, bool foundDigit)  //output if the password is invalid
{
    cout << "The password \"" << password << "\" is invalid for the following reasons:\n";
    if(longEnough == false)
    {
        cout << "The password has less than 8 characters\n";
    }
    if(foundUpper == false)
    {
        cout << "The password does not contain an uppercase letter\n";
    }
    if(foundLower == false)
    {
        cout << "The password does not contain a lowercase letter\n";
    }
    if(foundDigit == false)
    {
        cout << "The password does not contain a digit\n";
    }
}

#endif // PASSWORDS_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: What input do you pass in?

Comment: On an unrelated note, ` exit(0); //end program` isn't needed. If there's no explicit `return` statement at the end of the `main` function, the compiler will add a `return 0` there, which does the same thing.

Comment: On another unrelated note, if you have `if (condition) { return true; } else { return false; }`, it's actually the same as `return condition;`.

Comment: `== true` can be omitted, you just compare true with true or false with true that give again true or false.

Comment: Furthermore, defining (implementing) non-inline or non-static functions in a header file only works for when only a single source file includes that header file. If you have a project with two or more source files that include that header file, you will have multiple definition errors when linking.

Comment: `std::islower()`, `std::isupper()`, etc return an `int`, not a `bool`.    The test `islower(...) == true` will only be true if `islower()` returns the value `1`, since `true` will be promoted to `int` to do the comparison.   There is no guarantee that `islower()` returns `1` vif the argument is lower case, only that it returns non-zero.  Same for the other functions, but it seems you got "lucky".

Comment: `//reset bools to false` -- The `validatePass` function should be doing this, not `main`.  What if the caller "forgets" to initialize those variables to false?  Just that one aspect alone can throw `validatePass` off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your checks are wrong:

> ```
>     if(isupper(position) == true)   //check for uppercase letters
>     {
>         foundUpper = true;
>     }
> ```

[`std::isupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isupper):

> ```
> int isupper( int ch );
> ```
>
> Checks if the given character is an uppercase character as classified by the currently installed C locale. In the default "C" locale, `std::isupper` returns a nonzero value only for the uppercase letters (ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ).

In your comparison `true` is promoted to `int`, ie `1`, and any nonzero value different from `1` returned from `isupper` will make `isupper(position) == true` yield `false`, because eg `2 == 1` is `false`.

Change the comparisons to

```
     if(isupper(position))
     {
         foundUpper = true;
     }
```

`int` can be converted to `bool` and then any nonzero value yields `true`.

Same for `islower` and `isdigit`.

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rWxWWKazT)

Comment: Interesting, so the implementation of standard library actually returns something different than `0` or `1`? Is it doing `return ch & 32;` (assuming ASCII-like encoding) internally?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen For example, glibc's [implementation of the isxxx functions](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/tree/6d7e8eda9b85b08f207a6dc6f187e94e4817270f/ctype/ctype.c#L23-L36) returns the [bit-masked](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/tree/6d7e8eda9b85b08f207a6dc6f187e94e4817270f/ctype/ctype.h#L46-L60) result of a table value [as is](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/tree/6d7e8eda9b85b08f207a6dc6f187e94e4817270f/ctype/isctype.c#L25-L26).